# Removing div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a div element with javascript.I have following code but for some reason it is not working

HTML:

```
<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/car.png' %}" class="brand"><button onclick="removediv()">-</button>  </div>
<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/abc.png' %}" class="brand"><button onclick="removediv()">-</button>  </div>
<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/bat.png' %}" class="brand"><button onclick="removediv()">-</button>  </div>
<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/dog.png' %}" class="brand"><button onclick="removediv()">-</button>  </div>
```

my JS

```
function removediv(input) {
    document.getElementById('yes-drop').removeChild(input.parentNode);
}
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hcnrbu3k/3/)

In the fiddle I want to remove the element once when it is dragged.(After dragging a clone of element is formed

**Update 1**

My main aim is that I should be able to remove any of those element when I click the button for that particular element

**Update 2**

In my fiddle when I drag a element a copy of that element is created.I want to remove/delete that copy of element when button is clicked

Comment: duplicate id is invalid in html

Comment: so each element should have unique id in that case ?

Comment: If you want it in Javascript then why you have added jQuery tag?

Comment: Any of it is acceptd no compulsion of js or jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make the `id` unique for all divs.

See below snippet, I have used jQuery to remove the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) parent element.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.draggable').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/car.png' %}" class="brand"><button>-</button> </div>
<div class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/abc.png' %}" class="brand"><button>-</button> </div>
<div class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/bat.png' %}" class="brand"><button>-</button> </div>
<div class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/dog.png' %}" class="brand"><button>-</button> </div>
```

If the draggable elements are dynamically created then try the below code,

```
$(document).on('click','.draggable .removediv',function () { // let button has class removediv
  $(this).closest('.drag-drop').remove();
});
```

Comment: Closest as in always the last element will be removed ?

Comment: Closest http://api.jquery.com/closest/ will get the closest parent of which you click a button.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but when you refer my fiddle you can see that I need to remove the element which is dragged

Comment: In my fiddle there are 3 basic elements when I drag them a copy of that element is created and I want to remove that copy with the click of button

Comment: I am not able to remove the dragged element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167323/discussion-between-newbie-and-rohan-kumar).

Comment: is it possible that once i dropped a dynamically created div in a widget it will be in the boundaries of that div(I want to lock the position of the new div inside dropped div so that when I move the widget the div will also move)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you need to pass the `event` parameter in `onclick` function and you can remove using like this

```
function removediv(e) {
 e.target.parentNode.remove()
}
```

In this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njdhv10/hcnrbu3k/66/)**, I have done modification. I hope this will guide you.

```js
function removediv(e) {
 e.target.parentNode.remove()
}
```

```css
textarea {
 resize: none;
 overflow: scroll;
 width: 80%;
}



#target {
 position: relative;
}

#outer-dropzone {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.dropzone {
 background-color: #ccc;
 border: dashed 4px transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin: 10px auto 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 80%;
 transition: background-color 0.3s;
  
}

.drop-active {
 border-color: #aaa;
}
.drop-target {
 background-color: #29e;
 border-color: #fff;
 border-style: solid;
  
}

.drag-drop {
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 40px;
 padding: 2em 0.5em;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #29e;
 border: solid 2px #fff;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 transition: background-color 0.3s;
  z-index: 9999;
}


#yes-drop img {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <div class="gridster">
    <table border="1" class=".table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone 1</th>
        <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone 2</th>
        <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 1</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 2</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 3</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 4</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 1</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 2</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 3</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 4</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 1</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 2</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 3</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="outer-dropzone" class="dropzone">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add-button btn btn-success mr-2">Add widget</button>


<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/72-200.png" height="30" width="30" class="brand"><button onclick="removediv(event)">-</button></div>

<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/72-200.png" height="30" width="30" class="brand"><button onclick="removediv(event)">-</button></div>

<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/72-200.png" height="30" width="30" class="brand"><button onclick="removediv(event)">-</button></div>
```

Comment: Yup perfect Thanks for it :)